# Child not Responding

Tags: c, process

Hello I'm having issues with sending signals from the father process to the child process. The Child doesn't respond to the signed sent by the father process:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

if(pid > 0) {
printf("Hello, my son!\n");
    sleep(5); /* Sleep for 5 seconds... */
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
    printf("Goodbye, son!\n");
    }
else {
    printf("Son is running\n");
    pause(); /* Wait for some signal... */
    printf("I received the signal!");
    }
}
```

The son doesn't received the signal it only says it's running here is the output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd3Ts.png)

Comment: It's not "father".  It is "parent" and "child".

Comment: The default behavior when the signal is received is termination.  You need to handle the signal.

Comment: how can I handle the signal?
tysm for answering

Comment: Read the documentation on `sigaction`.  There are many examples available.

Comment: "pause() causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a signal is delivered that either terminates the process or causes the invocation of a signal-catching function." And well, that's what happened. It waited until the process was terminated by signal

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior when SIGUSR1 is received is termination, so the child never prints the message.  To handle the signal, you can use sigaction:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handle(int sig, siginfo_t *i, void *v) { return; }

int
main(void)
{
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if( pid > 0 ){
                printf("Hello, my child!\n");
                sleep(1); /* Sleep for 1 second. */
                kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
                printf("Goodbye, child!\n");
        } else {
                struct sigaction act;
                memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
                act.sa_sigaction = handle;

                if( sigaction( SIGUSR1, &act, NULL ) ){
                        perror("sigaction");
                        exit(1);
                }

                printf("Child is running\n");
                pause(); /* Wait for some signal... */
                printf("I received the signal!\n");
        }
}
```